# Json reader exception when I try to read a file

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In my application I have the possibility to insert a note, and I create it with this method:

```
public class Note
    {
        public string FraseGiorno { get; set; }
        public string Nota { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }  

string NotesFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Note.json");


ObservableCollection<Note> listNote = new ObservableCollection<Note>();

private async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await CreateNote.TranslateTo(0, 600, 500, Easing.SinIn);

        Note NoteNew = new Note();

        if (CheckBox.IsChecked = true)
        {
            NoteNew = new Note
            {
                FraseGiorno = obj1.FraseGiornaliera,
                Nota = TestoNota.Text,
                Data = DateTime.Today.ToString().Remove(10, 9),
            };
        }
        else
        {
            NoteNew = new Note
            {
                Nota = TestoNota.Text,
                Data = DateTime.Today.ToString().Remove(10, 9),
            };
        }

        using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(NotesFile))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(file, NoteNew);
        }

        listNote.Add(NoteNew);

    }
```

When the user moves to another page he has the possibility to read his notes:

```
if (File.Exists(NotesFile))
        {
            var Note = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Note>(File.ReadAllText(NotesFile));
        }
```

Here throw an exception but I don't understand why

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered
> after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 1, position 34.'
> Blockquote

Comment: it sounds like there is additional text after the end of the json content.  Since you didn't post the actual json there is no way for us to say for sure.

Comment: From the tests I have done it seems that this exception comes when I have not entered any notes inside the json file. If, on the other hand, there is at least one, everything works fine. Or at least it seems. I have no way to publish the json because it is created automatically by the application through the method I published.

Comment: You have no way to publish the json created by your own app?  Why don't you just prevent the file from saving if it contains no data?  Generally it is a good idea to prevent your app from generating bad data.

Comment: The app cannot save empty files with my method, but another problem, every time I go to the page where it reads me the notes entered, even if in reality it should save everything in a file, every time I reopen the app, the notes disappear. I don't know how to extract the json file

Comment: That is a different problem that what you originally posted about.  Please focus on one issue at a time.  It would still help tremendously if you would post the json that causes the exception.

Comment: Can you advise me how to recover it?

Comment: Use the debugger.  Or write it to the console.  Or grab the file directly from the filesystem.  Or display it in an alert when you read it.  What exactly do you not understand how to do?

Comment: @StefanoSton Hi, you could share the content of **NotesFile** in question, then I will check where problem is.

Comment: [screen](https://i.postimg.cc/DZ2vCZw2/screen.jpg) Where is the problem? everything should work fine, isn't it?

Comment: @StefanoSton I have updated the solution in answer. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

From the shared string data, you need to surround that with square brackets, which denotes that it's an array:

```
[{"Nota":"ooo","Data":"14/01/2021"},{"Nota":"S02","Data":"15/01/2021"}]
```

Comment: This code Is correct? 'Note[] Note = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Note>(File.ReadAllText(NotesFile));'

Comment: @StefanoSton Not correct. Replace `Note[] Note` with `List<Note> note`. And you could spearate them with two line code to check each of line whether return value. For example: `string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);List<Note> note = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Note>(text);`

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[MotiVApp.NotePage+Note]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.....                     I have to write the code like this in order not to receive errors from VisualStudio, otherwise the compilation of the application will not start
`List<Note> note = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Note>>(text)`

Comment: @StefanoSton Hi, do you check the string data whether is my shared style? `[{"Nota":"ooo","Data":"14/01/2021"},{"Nota":"S02","Data":"15/01/2021"}]`. My shaed style means that you need to modify the content of local file.

Comment: I managed to insert the square bracket at the beginning and at the end of the string, but how do I insert the comma "," between the various objects? `string text = File.ReadAllText(NotesFile).Insert(0, "[");
                string textt = text.Insert(text.Length, "]");
                Note[] note = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Note[]>(textt);`

Comment: @StefanoSton Hi, why not directly add them by editting local file(`NotesFile`)? Generally , the json string file is generated by other platforms, not need Xamarin to modify them. Xamarin only need to deserialize it and get the data.

Comment: Hi, so what would you advise me to do? thanks

Comment: @StefanoSton I mean that you could edit the local file(NotesFile) directly to fit the style of json. Not need to modify the file programmatically.